# Нос и носок

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Интересно, а что общего у носа и носка? Вроде как совершенно противоположные части тела — носок-то на ногу надевается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, носок (и часть тела, и предмет одежды) родственно нос. В основе - "нос", нечто выступающее.